# Android: correct way to get screen dimensions for target orientation?

Tags: android, layout, screen

My application is bitmap intensive, with pixel-exact layout (it's a sort of game, actually, and it's pretty hard to avoid this pixel-based coordinates).

What I wanted to do is to perform some layout calculations and bitmap pre-scaling in my `onCrete` - I use well known API - `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize()` - to retrieve the screen size and do my calculations.

However, I've just hit an unexpected problem. My activity is configured as landscape only, but if I start my application on emulator and `onCreate()` is called while the emulator is locked, the screen size returned by `getSize()` indicates portrait orientation. Once I unlock the screen, `onCreate()` is called again, this time correctly in line with expected landscape mode dimensions.

I'm not sure how to handle this situation. I see the following options:

- for each `onCreate()` call perform full layout calculation and resource scaling again. This is the logically correct solution, but I don't want to the same work twice, just to throw away the first result.
- if `onCreate()` is called for portrait mode, just do nothing, and set black background (I can see there's a silly rotate animation when I unlock the screen, so this would become pretty much a fade-in animation)

Actually I'd prefer second option, but I'm slightly afraid of any side-effects. Anyone faced this problem?

**Update (2012-07-08)**: 
I've probably assigned a slightly misleading title to this question (sorry!), as the problem is not in retrieving the dimensions itself, nor calculating the layout. It's more about the activity being first created in portrait mode, and then recreated in landscape mode again, despite being declared as landscape-only. I initially expected (reasonably, huh?) the activity to be created in landscape orientation only.

I eventually decided to fill the activity with black color when it's created in portrait mode, no side effects observed. On Android 4.0 I can see actual rotation animation when I unlock the screen - a bit strange, but well, I guess it is supposed to inform the user that she should rotate the phone. Given that in portrait mode I just fill the screen with black color, this animation looks sort of like a fade-in and rotation combined - perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Use that

```
DisplayMetrics dm=new DisplayMetrics(); 

this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
```

Using this(Look code at down) only gives you screen size and if your views has static size they will be seen in different size on every different screen.

```
Display screen=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize();
```

How to use:
every screen has diffrent density. So use:

```
float density=dm.density;
```

with this density, you can set your views size like that:

```
(YOUR_ITEM_SIZE)*density;
```

also look here for additional information:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood my original question. It's not the problem with scaling the view, I know how to do it (in my question I mentioned getDefaultDisplay().getSize() already). And in this particular app I don't care about density, really, because I have pixel-exact full-screen layouts, which I calculate on my own, regardless of screen density.

Answer (score 0):

if the emulator is locked , can't you assume that the user can't run anything anyway , so the app doesn't need to handle this end case ?

anyway , as `bmavus` wrote , use `getMetrics` for getting the screen size . also , if you need to change the screen orientation of the app , you can do so either in the manifest or in code.

for games , i would advice using opengl solutions , and if you don't have much time digging for it , you can use third party engines that can help you , such as [`andengine`](http://www.andengine.org/blog/) and [`libgdx`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/).

Comment: I'm afraid my question was misunderstood. Indeed, my activity can't be operated while the screen is locked. The problem is, that onCreate() is called for portrait mode when application starts, if screen is locked. When I unlock the screen, onCreate() is called again, this time with landscape orientation, as expected.

Comment: Actually I decided to for my second option - just load and display nothing until activity is created in landscape mode (as declated in manifest). No side effects seen so far.